# Can I configure VLC to cache entire playlists?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, cache

I stream albums from my server, using the VLC's playlist functionality. VLC seemingly doesn't cache the upcoming tracks at all and loading the next one seems to often take around 30 seconds (re-establishes the server connection, then presumably downloads the entire song).

[image: screenshot]

---

I assume that the "stream output" settings only apply to the supported web streams, such as YouTube, and not specifically to a remote server.

Comment: I don't know about media server. I think there is an option in 'Media' menu to save playlist in a file.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Does this feature save any data related to the files itself?

Comment: The playlist file only saves the file name, path and play order.